# FANCYBOX next imagegallery

Tags: fancybox

I would like to add functionality to the fancybox, I replaced the arrows with dots I have added a button to open and close the description: like this:

```
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            arrows:true,
            padding : 0,

            beforeShow: function () {

                        this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
                        this.title = '<h4 class="titles">' + this.title + '</h4>'/* + '<div class="description">' + $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt') +'</div>'*/;

                        this.description = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
                        this.description ='<div class="description">'  + this.description +'</div>';
                        $(this.description).appendTo(this.inner);

                        if (this.title) {
                            // New line
                            this.title += '';


                        }
                        if (this.description) {
                            // New line
                            this.description += '';


                        }

                        $(".description").hide();

                    },

            afterShow: function() { 

                $('<div class="expander"></div>').appendTo(this.inner).click(function() {
                    $(".description").slideToggle("fast");
                });
            },

            helpers : {
                title : { type: 'inside' }
            },

            afterLoad   : addLinks, 
            beforeClose : removeLinks
        });

        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });

        function addLinks() {
            var list = $("#links");

            if (!list.length) {    
                list = $('<ul id="links">');

                for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
                    $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
                }

                list.appendTo( 'body' );
            }

            list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq( this.index ).addClass('active');
        }

        function removeLinks() {
            $("#links").remove();    
        }
```

then I define some galleries using the "rel" attribute …

```
  <!-- Start Project -->
<div class="fphotography"> <a href="image1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY1" title="GALLERY1">
<div class="img-wrp"> <img class="scaleimg" src="image1.jpg" width="220" height="140" alt="DESC" />
 </div>
 </a>
 <p class="project-title">TITLE</p>
<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY1" title="GALLERY1" href="image1A.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY1" title="GALLERY1" href="image1B.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY1" title="GALLERY1" href="image1C.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
</div>
 </div>
 <!-- End Project -->

          <!-- Start Project -->
<div class="photography"> <a href="image2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY2" title="GALLERY2">
<div class="img-wrp"> <img class="scaleimg" src="image2.jpg" width="220" height="140" alt="DESC" />
 </div>
 </a>
 <p class="project-title">TITLE</p>
<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY2" title="GALLERY2" href="image2A.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY2" title="GALLERY2" href="image2B.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY2" title="GALLERY2" href="image2C.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
</div>
 </div> 

<!-- End Project -->
<!-- Start Project -->

<div class="photography"> <a href="image3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY3" title="GALLERY3">
<div class="img-wrp"> <img class="scaleimg" src="image3.jpg" width="220" height="140" alt="DESC" />
 </div>
 </a>
 <p class="project-title">TITLE</p>
<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY3" title="GALLERY3" href="image3A.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY3" title="GALLERY3" href="image3B.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="GALLERY3" title="GALLERY3" href="image3C.jpg" ><img src="#" alt="DESC"/></a>
</div>
 </div>

<!-- End Project -->
```

Now I would like to add two buttons when the fancy box is open that go to the next or previous gallery.

Does anybody know how to do that? any ideas?

Thany you very much in advantage..

Comment: I guess you still want to be able to navigate through a single gallery so you want 2 additional buttons apart from those used by the gallery, don't you?

Comment: I want that the two buttons normally used by the gallery open instead the next gallery .. it's possible?  alternatively okay even add two additional buttons.